# Docusign document sends blank or black pages

Tags: docusignapi

we have an application that sends a file to docusign using rest web services.  it then opens up the document and allows the person to put their signature blocks etc on the document and send it out.  The document looks OK at that point but the person receiving reports all blank or black pages.  It only happens intermittently.  < 1% of the time.

Comment: Please clarify your question and add relevant code if you are hoping for resolution of this issue.  Also, you're saying it happens less than 1% of the time?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with the "client" -- not an issue with the DocuSign Envelope itself (and the DocuSign service).  i.e., perhaps the recipient's poor internet connectivity or browser issues are preventing their envelope from rendering completely/correctly.  To verify the validity of the DocuSign Envelope when you receive a report of this happening, you could have the ***sender*** login to the DocuSign console and open the Envelope (via double-click) from their **Sent Items** folder -- if the Envelope opens okay (i.e., documents are complete and rendered properly), then this would suggest that it's not an issue with the Envelope that's causing the recipient's issues, but rather, more likely an issue with the recipient's internet connectivity, browser, etc.

Also, when a recipient experiences this issue, I'd be curious to know what happens if they try opening the Envelope again, and/or try using a different type of browser to open the Envelope.  If either of these approaches is successful (i.e., the Envelope opens and renders correctly), that would suggest some type of (intermittent) issue on the client (receiving) end of things.

Comment: if the PDF is downloaded the pages are blank and there is a message that says insufficient data for an image.  It has 2 pages that are blank and I think they are the pages that the signature boxes were on.